# How to speed up Ruby script? Or shell script alternative?

Tags: ruby, shell

I have a Ruby script that does the following to a text file:

1. removes non-ASCII lines
2. removes lines containing "::" (two colons in a row)
3. if there is more than one ":" present in the line (which aren't directly next to each other), it only keeps the strings on both sides of the last colon.
4. removes leading whitespace
5. removes unusual control characters

The problem is, I'm working with files that have ~20 million lines, and my script says it'll take ~45 minutes to run.

Is there a way to majorly speed this up? Or, is there a significantly quicker way to handle this in shell?

```
require 'ruby-progressbar'

class String
  def strip_control_characters()
    chars.each_with_object("") do |char, str|
      str << char unless char.ascii_only? and (char.ord < 32 or char.ord == 127)
    end
  end

  def strip_control_and_extended_characters()
    chars.each_with_object("") do |char, str|
      str << char if char.ascii_only? and char.ord.between?(32,126)
    end
  end
end

class Numeric
   def percent_of(n)
    self.to_f / n.to_f * 100.0
   end
end

def clean(file_in,file_out)
    if !File.exists?(file_in)
        puts "File '#{file_in}' does not exist."
        return
    end

    File.delete(file_out) if File.exist?(file_out)
    `touch #{file_out}`

    deleted = 0
    count = 0

    line_count = `wc -l "#{file_in}"`.strip.split(' ')[0].to_i
    puts "File has #{line_count} lines. Cleaning..."

    progressbar = ProgressBar.create(total: line_count, length: 100, format: 'Progress |%B| %a %e')


    IO.foreach(file_in) {|x|
        if x.ascii_only?
            line = x.strip_control_and_extended_characters.strip
            if line == ""
                deleted += 1
                next
            end
            if line.include?("::")
                deleted += 1
                next
            end
            split = line.split(":")

            c = split.count
            if c == 1
                deleted += 1
                next
            end
            if c > 2
                line = split.last(2).join(":")
            end

            if line != ""
                File.open(file_out, 'a') { |f| f.puts(line) }
            else
                deleted += 1
            end
        else
            deleted += 1
        end

        progressbar.progress += 1
    }

    puts "Deleted #{deleted} lines."
end
```

Comment: Have you tried [multithreading](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html)? Basically does 2 processes at the same time.

Comment: I meant to try it but I haven't really figured out how to implement multiple threads when reading in a file like this. Would I do a thread pool and put the line read within a pool.process section?

Comment: You could take advantage of parallelism if you broke your 5 transformations (A, B, C, D, E) into a number of different programs and use Unix pipes to connect their inputs to their outputs.  Or they could be several different threads in the same program that are connected via queues in the same way.  It might not make a difference though, if your program is mostly just waiting for I/O system calls.

Comment: that would only help if Max used jRuby, not MRI Ruby (no real mutitasking in MRI), jRuby would also speed thing up by itself but the code can be optimized a lot, thats's the first thing to do. you should break up the tasks in separate methods that you can test and benchmark each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one of your big problems:

```
if line != ""
  File.open(file_out, 'a') { |f| f.puts(line) }
end
```

So your program needs to open and close the output file millions of times because it is doing that for every single line.  Each time it opens it, since it is being opened in append mode, your system might have to do a lot of work to find the end of the file.

You should really change your program to open the output file once at the beginning and only close it at the end.  Also, run `strace` to see what your Ruby I/O operations are doing behind the scenes; it should buffer up the writes and then send them to the OS in blocks of about 4 kilobytes at a time; it shouldn't issue a `write` system call for every single line.

To further improve the performance, you should use a Ruby profiling tool to see which functions are taking the most time.

Comment: There has been a lot of good information in these posts, so thank you everyone! David, I marked yours as the answer since that File call was a *huge* slowdown in my code. I initially wrote it that way thinking that it would save memory since I'm loading in very large text files, but this (much) faster way seems to be working fine.

Comment: Either way is pretty memory efficient because an open file handle does not take much memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the speed by changing your String additions to variations on:

```
class String
  def strip_control_characters()
    gsub(/[[:cntrl:]]+/, '')
  end

  def strip_control_and_extended_characters()
    strip_control_characters.gsub(/[^[:ascii:]]+/, '')
  end
end

str = (0..255).to_a.map { |b| b.chr }.join # => "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\x0E\x0F\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1A\e\x1C\x1D\x1E\x1F !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7F\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8A\x8B\x8C\x8D\x8E\x8F\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9A\x9B\x9C\x9D\x9E\x9F\xA0\xA1\xA2\xA3\xA4\xA5\xA6\xA7\xA8\xA9\xAA\xAB\xAC\xAD\xAE\xAF\xB0\xB1\xB2\xB3\xB4\xB5\xB6\xB7\xB8\xB9\xBA\xBB\xBC\xBD\xBE\xBF\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3\xC4\xC5\xC6\xC7\xC8\xC9\xCA\xCB\xCC\xCD\xCE\xCF\xD0\xD1\xD2\xD3\xD4\xD5\xD6\xD7\xD8\xD9\xDA\xDB\xDC\xDD\xDE\xDF\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE4\xE5\xE6\xE7\xE8\xE9\xEA\xEB\xEC\xED\xEE\xEF\xF0\xF1\xF2\xF3\xF4\xF5\xF6\xF7\xF8\xF9\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFD\xFE\xFF"

str.strip_control_characters 
# => " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8A\x8B\x8C\x8D\x8E\x8F\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9A\x9B\x9C\x9D\x9E\x9F\xA0\xA1\xA2\xA3\xA4\xA5\xA6\xA7\xA8\xA9\xAA\xAB\xAC\xAD\xAE\xAF\xB0\xB1\xB2\xB3\xB4\xB5\xB6\xB7\xB8\xB9\xBA\xBB\xBC\xBD\xBE\xBF\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3\xC4\xC5\xC6\xC7\xC8\xC9\xCA\xCB\xCC\xCD\xCE\xCF\xD0\xD1\xD2\xD3\xD4\xD5\xD6\xD7\xD8\xD9\xDA\xDB\xDC\xDD\xDE\xDF\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE4\xE5\xE6\xE7\xE8\xE9\xEA\xEB\xEC\xED\xEE\xEF\xF0\xF1\xF2\xF3\xF4\xF5\xF6\xF7\xF8\xF9\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFD\xFE\xFF"

str.strip_control_and_extended_characters 
# => " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
```

Use the built-in `gsub` method along with the POSIX character-sets instead of iterating over the strings and testing each character.

As @Myst said though, monkey-patching is rude. Use [refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), or create some methods and pass in the string:

```
def strip_control_characters(str)
  str.gsub(/[[:cntrl:]]+/, '')
end

def strip_control_and_extended_characters(str)
  strip_control_characters(str).gsub(/[^[:ascii:]]+/, '')
end

str = (0..255).to_a.map { |b| b.chr }.join # => "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\x0E\x0F\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1A\e\x1C\x1D\x1E\x1F !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7F\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8A\x8B\x8C\x8D\x8E\x8F\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9A\x9B\x9C\x9D\x9E\x9F\xA0\xA1\xA2\xA3\xA4\xA5\xA6\xA7\xA8\xA9\xAA\xAB\xAC\xAD\xAE\xAF\xB0\xB1\xB2\xB3\xB4\xB5\xB6\xB7\xB8\xB9\xBA\xBB\xBC\xBD\xBE\xBF\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3\xC4\xC5\xC6\xC7\xC8\xC9\xCA\xCB\xCC\xCD\xCE\xCF\xD0\xD1\xD2\xD3\xD4\xD5\xD6\xD7\xD8\xD9\xDA\xDB\xDC\xDD\xDE\xDF\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE4\xE5\xE6\xE7\xE8\xE9\xEA\xEB\xEC\xED\xEE\xEF\xF0\xF1\xF2\xF3\xF4\xF5\xF6\xF7\xF8\xF9\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFD\xFE\xFF"

strip_control_characters(str)
# => " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8A\x8B\x8C\x8D\x8E\x8F\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9A\x9B\x9C\x9D\x9E\x9F\xA0\xA1\xA2\xA3\xA4\xA5\xA6\xA7\xA8\xA9\xAA\xAB\xAC\xAD\xAE\xAF\xB0\xB1\xB2\xB3\xB4\xB5\xB6\xB7\xB8\xB9\xBA\xBB\xBC\xBD\xBE\xBF\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3\xC4\xC5\xC6\xC7\xC8\xC9\xCA\xCB\xCC\xCD\xCE\xCF\xD0\xD1\xD2\xD3\xD4\xD5\xD6\xD7\xD8\xD9\xDA\xDB\xDC\xDD\xDE\xDF\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE4\xE5\xE6\xE7\xE8\xE9\xEA\xEB\xEC\xED\xEE\xEF\xF0\xF1\xF2\xF3\xF4\xF5\xF6\xF7\xF8\xF9\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFD\xFE\xFF"

strip_control_and_extended_characters(str)
# => " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
```

Moving on...

```
`touch #{file_out}`
```

is a problem too. You're create a sub-shell every time that runs, executing `touch` then tearing it down which is a slow operation. Let Ruby do it:

```
=== Implementation from FileUtils
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  touch(list, noop: nil, verbose: nil, mtime: nil, nocreate: nil)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updates modification time (mtime) and access time (atime) of file(s) in list.
Files are created if they don't exist.

  FileUtils.touch 'timestamp'
  FileUtils.touch Dir.glob('*.c');  system 'make'
```

Finally, learn to benchmark code as you develop. Take the time to think of a couple ways to do something, then test them against each other and find out which is the fastest. I use [Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity), because it handles issues that the [Benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) class doesn't, but do one or the other. You can find a lot of tests I did here for various things by searching SO for my user and "benchmark".

```
require 'fruity'

class String
  def strip_control_characters()
    chars.each_with_object("") do |char, str|
      str << char unless char.ascii_only? and (char.ord < 32 or char.ord == 127)
    end
  end

  def strip_control_and_extended_characters()
    chars.each_with_object("") do |char, str|
      str << char if char.ascii_only? and char.ord.between?(32,126)
    end
  end
end

def strip_control_characters2(str)
  str.gsub(/[[:cntrl:]]+/, '')
end

def strip_control_and_extended_characters2(str)
  strip_control_characters2(str).gsub(/[^[:ascii:]]+/, '')
end

str = (0..255).to_a.map { |b| b.chr }.join 

str.strip_control_characters   # => " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8A\x8B\x8C\x8D\x8E\x8F\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9A\x9B\x9C\x9D\x9E\x9F\xA0\xA1\xA2\xA3\xA4\xA5\xA6\xA7\xA8\xA9\xAA\xAB\xAC\xAD\xAE\xAF\xB0\xB1\xB2\xB3\xB4\xB5\xB6\xB7\xB8\xB9\xBA\xBB\xBC\xBD\xBE\xBF\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3\xC4\xC5\xC6\xC7\xC8\xC9\xCA\xCB\xCC\xCD\xCE\xCF\xD0\xD1\xD2\xD3\xD4\xD5\xD6\xD7\xD8\xD9\xDA\xDB\xDC\xDD\xDE\xDF\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE4\xE5\xE6\xE7\xE8\xE9\xEA\xEB\xEC\xED\xEE\xEF\xF0\xF1\xF2\xF3\xF4\xF5\xF6\xF7\xF8\xF9\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFD\xFE\xFF"
strip_control_characters2(str) # => " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8A\x8B\x8C\x8D\x8E\x8F\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9A\x9B\x9C\x9D\x9E\x9F\xA0\xA1\xA2\xA3\xA4\xA5\xA6\xA7\xA8\xA9\xAA\xAB\xAC\xAD\xAE\xAF\xB0\xB1\xB2\xB3\xB4\xB5\xB6\xB7\xB8\xB9\xBA\xBB\xBC\xBD\xBE\xBF\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3\xC4\xC5\xC6\xC7\xC8\xC9\xCA\xCB\xCC\xCD\xCE\xCF\xD0\xD1\xD2\xD3\xD4\xD5\xD6\xD7\xD8\xD9\xDA\xDB\xDC\xDD\xDE\xDF\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE4\xE5\xE6\xE7\xE8\xE9\xEA\xEB\xEC\xED\xEE\xEF\xF0\xF1\xF2\xF3\xF4\xF5\xF6\xF7\xF8\xF9\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFD\xFE\xFF"

str.strip_control_and_extended_characters   # => " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
strip_control_and_extended_characters2(str) # => " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"

compare do
  scc { str.strip_control_characters }
  scc2 { strip_control_characters2(str) }
end

# >> Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> scc2 is faster than scc by 10x ± 1.0
```

and:

```
compare do
  scec { str.strip_control_and_extended_characters }
  scec2 { strip_control_and_extended_characters2(str) }
end

# >> Running each test 256 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> scec2 is faster than scec by 5x ± 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be only to possible approaches to optimizing this:

1. Concurrency.

   If your machine is a Unix/Linux based machine that has a multi-core CPU, you can take advantage of the multi-cores by using `fork`, dividing up the work between different processes.

   Multi-threading might not work as well as you'd expect with Ruby, since there's a GIL (Global Instruction Lock) that prevents multiple threads from running together.
2. Code optimizations.

   These include minimizing system calls (such as the `File.open`) and minimizing any temporary objects.

   I would start with this approach before I moved on to `fork`, mainly due to the extra coding required when using `fork`.

   The first approach requires a large rewrite of the script, while the second approach might be more easily achieved.

For example, the following approach minimizes some system calls (such as the File's `open`, `close` and `write` system calls):

```
require 'ruby-progressbar'

class String
  def strip_control_characters()
    chars.each_with_object("") do |char, str|
      str << char unless char.ascii_only? and (char.ord < 32 or char.ord == 127)
    end
  end

  def strip_control_and_extended_characters()
    chars.each_with_object("") do |char, str|
      str << char if char.ascii_only? and char.ord.between?(32,126)
    end
  end
end

class Numeric
   def percent_of(n)
    self.to_f / n.to_f * 100.0
   end
end

def clean(file_in,file_out)
    if !File.exists?(file_in)
        puts "File '#{file_in}' does not exist."
        return
    end

    File.delete(file_out) if File.exist?(file_out)
    `touch #{file_out}`

    deleted = 0
    count = 0

    line_count = `wc -l "#{file_in}"`.strip.split(' ')[0].to_i
    puts "File has #{line_count} lines. Cleaning..."

    progressbar = ProgressBar.create(total: line_count, length: 100, format: 'Progress |%B| %a %e')

    file_fd = File.open(file_out, 'a')
    buffer = "".dup

    IO.foreach(file_in) {|x|
        if x.ascii_only?
            line = x.strip_control_and_extended_characters.strip
            if line == ""
                deleted += 1
                next
            end
            if line.include?("::")
                deleted += 1
                next
            end
            split = line.split(":")

            c = split.count
            if c == 1
                deleted += 1
                next
            end
            if c > 2
                line = split.last(2).join(":")
            end

            if line != ""
                buffer += "\r\n#{line}"
            else
                deleted += 1
            end
        else
            deleted += 1
        end

        if buffer.length >= 2048
           file_fd.puts(buffer)
           buffer.clear
        end
        progressbar.progress += 1
    }

    file_fd.puts(buffer)
    buffer.clear
    file_fd.close
    puts "Deleted #{deleted} lines."
end
```

P.S.

I would avoid monkey patching - it's rude.

---

After posting this I read @DavidGrayson's answer, which pinpoints an issue with your code's performance in a much shorter and succinct answer.

I up-voted his answer, as I think you'll get a big performance gain from this simple change.